# Refresh iFrame (Cache Issue)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We are getting a weird issue on which we are not sure what exactly cause it. Let me elaborate the issue. Suppose, we have two different html pages a.html and b.html. And a little script written in index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function reloadFrame(iframe, src) {
        iframe.src = src;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
        <input type="button" value="Load a.html" onclick="reloadFrame(document.getElementById('myFrame'), 'a.html')">
        <input type="button" value="Load b.html" onclick="reloadFrame(document.getElementById('myFrame'), 'b.html')">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

A server component is continuously updating both files a.html and b.html. The problem is the content of both files are successfully updating on the server side.  If we open we can see the updated changes but client getting the older content which doesn't show the updated changes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this in a.html and b.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0" />
</head>
```

To force no cache checks

Comment: @Ben - there is nothing to suggest XHTML is being used in this question. For example, the inputs do not have closing tags either.

Comment: This solution don't work for me, please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451674/wrong-content-when-refresh-a-page-contains-iframes-in-ie)

Answer (score 12):

If you can add server-side instructions to those HTML files, you could send the appropriate headers to prevent caching:

[Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) (I think the consensus is that the 2nd answer is best, not the accepted one)

Simone's answer already deals with Meta tags.

A cheap quick trick is to add a random number as a GET parameter:

```
page_1.html?time=102398405820
```

if this changes on every request (e.g. using the current time), reloading wil get forced every time, too.

Comment: A caveat with a naive implementation of the random number trick is that you can end up with urls like `"page_1.html?time=123?time=456?time=789?time=012"` on repeated invocations. Harmless, but ugly IMHO.

Comment: Here is adding time to iframe.src in javascript. 
function reloadIframe()
{  
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
 var d = new Date();
iframe.src = iframe.src + "?"+ d.getTime();
}

Answer (score 10):

Try something like the following:

```
<script>
    var frameElement = document.getElementById("frame-id");
    frameElement.contentWindow.location.href = frameElement.src;
</script>
```

This will force the iframe to be reloaded even if it was cached by the browser

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

I want to put [Vishwas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524502/refresh-iframe-cache-issue#comment115445186_2524539) as a separate answer, extending
[Pekka’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524539/52277)

```
//ensure iframe is not cached
function reloadIframe(iframeId) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    var d = new Date();
    if (iframe) {
        iframe.src = iframe.src + '?ver=' + d.getTime();
        //alternatively frameElement.contentWindow.location.href = frameElement.src; //This will force the iframe to be reloaded even if it was cached by the browser
    }
}
reloadIframe('session_storage_check');
```

Answer (score 0):

Homero Barbosa's Solution worked like a charm.  In my case, I had a varying number of iframes on the page, so I did the following:

```
$('.some_selector').each(function () {
  var $randid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  $(this).attr({'id': 'goinOnaSafari-' + $randid});

  var $frame = document.getElementById('goinOnaSafari-' + $randid);
  $frame.contentWindow.location.href = $frame.src;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the HTML to work.

```
<head>
    <meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0" />
</head>
```

For development in chrome I checked the console Network tab and found where the iframe is loaded.
I confirmed that it was loaded with a 304 response wich means it loads from cache.
Right click -> clear browser cache.

Will not work in production, but at least helps with development.

Answer (score -1):

For one possible solution to this, pass a "cache parameter" to your calls to a.html and b.html.  For example

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Load a.html" onclick="cacheSafeReload('a.html');">
```

Javascript

```
function cacheSafeReload(urlBase) {
    var cacheParamValue = (new Date()).getTime();
    var url = urlBase + "?cache=" + cacheParamValue;
    reloadFrame(document.getElementById('myFrame'), url);
}
```