# fancybox makes multiple request on iframe

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox v2.1.5 for a .net application.
I use the iframe for displaying an aspx-side. Works fine. But today I noticed, that the request to my aspx-page to be displayed in a fancybox was made 4 times. I tested it with another page - same issue.

Here is all what I do:

```
<a href='ChangePassword.aspx' class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" style="color:white;text-decoration:none;">Change password</a>
```

This is the easy side, but in another there are some DB-Calls an many lines of code, so it isn't really a good thing because of the performance.

I've only found one very old link: [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/_tOHP71ynnI)

thx
©a-x-i

Comment: have you tried the API option `iframe: {preload: false}`? Fancybox also creates a new random ID for each iframe regardless is the same page to address the issue on the latest post you refer. also check http://stackoverflow.com/q/2648053/1055987 if that helps

Comment: No chance - same problem. The request is still made 4 times :(

Comment: I'm so silly. The $('.fancybox').fancybox(); was called many times. One time in master, one time in aspx, one time in ascx and.... in another script file too.
That's all.
thx a lot :)