# Placing Javascript ad zone in PHP function

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to place a javascript ad zone inside a php function.  I am doing this to control what ad zones are placed on each page. Currently in the php template I am using:

```
<?php
        if(is_page('welcome-president')) {
            oiopub_banner_zone(9);
            oiopub_banner_zone(19);
        } 
        ?>
```

I am trying to place this javascript code inside the if conditional tag instead of the oiopub_banner_zone(9); so that the ads will not be cached and rotate.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rutgers.myuvn.com/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php#type=banner&align=center&zone=9"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so remove the `(9)` line and put in `echo "<script .... /script>"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than call the function oiopub_banner_zone(9) to display the banner code, you can just replace that function call with echo and the actual script tag that you would like to output on the page.

```
<?php
    if(is_page('welcome-president')) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rutgers.myuvn.com/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php#type=banner&align=center&zone=9"></script>';
        oiopub_banner_zone(19);
    } 
?>
```

Comment: While this snippet might fix the issue, it would be nice to describe your approach so that future readers, having a different but similar issue, benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I just added a description.

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem while still allowing me to control the ad space manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent caching. Make an  that points to some place in your site ( e.g. /ad_iframe.php ) and do the rotate logic to retrieve the add content there. That will not get cached.

There was a post about it that helped me a lot.

[Preventing iframe caching in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648053/preventing-iframe-caching-in-browser)

Good luck, and cheers.