# Add random numbers to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i add an iframe to my web but everytime it cache the url so the best option for me is everytime to make link like this

```
http://example.com/ex.html?RANDOMNUMBERS

http://example.com/ex.html?123o8173oy12389
```

so it will not be cached 
how can i add example Math.random();  to my url
i try this but it doesnt work

```
<iframe id='iframe2' src="http://example.com/ex.html?<script>Math.random();</script>" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;
    width: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

(i can not use php)

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648053/preventing-iframe-caching-in-browser

Seems to be a FF bug and there's a javascript solution in there

Comment: you can't embed a script block inside an attribute like that. not possible in any way/shape/form.  you CAN have the js code SET the iframe's attribute, e.g. `<script>$('#iframe2').attr('src', 'http://.....' + Math.random();)</script><iframe ...>`

Comment: you cannot add javascript in-line like that. If you want to do this purely in javascript, you will need to dynamically create the iframe with `document.createElement`.  The alternative is to use server-side code to dynamically output the [static] iframe with the number

Comment: How do you add that iframe? Was it loaded along with the page or added via javascript?

Comment: You can also try use new Date().getTime()

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrl() {
  return "http://example.com/ex.html?rnd=" + new Date().getTime();
}
```

using

```
<iframe id='iframe2' src="javascript:top.getUrl()" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

I cannot test it here since it blocks on same origin policy when testing

Comment: is not contructive - what is not working? Console message?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work on its own when put between script tags. No need to create the element using HTML. Doing a console.dir on the iframe variable will show that the source is what we intend to get.

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/ex.html?' + Math.random();

iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden';
iframe.style.height = '100%';
iframe.style.width = '100%';
iframe.style.position = 'absolute';

document.body.innerHtml += iframe;
```