# How do I access my WordPress CSS ?

Tags: css, wordpress, ftp

I am trying to edit the background color to my CSS header. I tried accessing my CSS folder and according to my Developer tools console the CSS file's path should be  gcc/wp-content/themes/reconstruction/css/main.css

I ran my FTP server, followed the path and added some new CSS rules to the main.css, But when i update and refresh server and view the website through a browser it does not update and keeps the previous design almost as if it's the wrong file path? I have tried clearing my cache on both browsers and that has not worked either.

Here is the website where i am trying to change it's header www.greencalstateconstruction.com

I am trying to change the .mainHeader area's css into this:

```
.mainHeader {

background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(248, 237, 168), rgba(57, 204, 182, 0.74));
background-color: #ffefa7;
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Add to `themes/reconstruction/style.css` this in last line

Comment: Your whole website is loaded in a frame... [So it is cached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648053/preventing-iframe-caching-in-browser)

Comment: Okay, i tried this for another project - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to edit the source files of your WordPress templates, make a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). When you make modifications to your original theme, they will be overridden when you update the theme. Having a child theme keeps your modifications apart from the original theme.

If you can't create a child theme, you can modify the source files directly from the WordPress admin. Go into your admin panel, under the Appearance tab, you find the Editor section. Here you can edit the files directly from within the admin panel. Here you can edit all theme files. Try to find the style.css file and place your modifications here.