# does iframe not keep content up-to-date?

Tags: iis, iframe, reporting-services

I have an ssrs report..

It serves as an iframe on a page.

If I visit the report directly by going to `http://myreportserver/reportserver/report` then the report that is opened is up-to-date.

However, if I open the report by visiting a page where it is embedded as an iframe, it will show it as an older version.

is this the expected behavior of `iframes`? how do i force the iframe to load the most up-to-date version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2524518/1685810

Comment: What's your code to view this report using [tag:iframe]s?