# html iframe - used cached content instead of reload

Tags: html, css

So as you go from page to page in a web application the layout is cached by the browser, this means elements consistent across pages are not reloaded and instead loaded from the cache. Because the reload is so fast the user can go from page to page and it appears that those elements are not being reloaded and just remain in place.

The problem I am encountering is that if you have a iframe that loads consistent content from page to page the same behaviour is not observed. Instead the is a momentary flash where the iframe is empty and then loading takes place.

Is there anything that can be done to avoid this i.e have the browser load a cached version of the iframe content immediately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh iFrame (Cache Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524502/refresh-iframe-cache-issue)

Comment: Sorry that has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @user1209203 Have you confirmed from the `Network Tab` in DevTools that it is indeed not loaded from the cache?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides looking at it the cache is not being used.

Comment: you cannot prevent that because the iframe has its own document and the resources (img, video uso) in the iframe are loaded in another "window". You may force this if you use friendly iframes but with NFIframes no chance.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I have managed to have the iframe page cache but the flash still happens

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I'm not sure what you mean by a friendly iframe?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri The iframe is from the same tld and I have also added      inDapIF = true; and the flash still occurs.